# Is there a feature to summarize tests from multi trigger builds in tfs 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, automated-tests, tfsbuild

In my builds I trigger some 'mini' builds that run tests.
Each build that finish summarize to me how many tests in this run failed/passed.

I'm looking for a way to summarize all the builds that were triggered and their results in the main build.

Does there is a way or a feature that support its?
In TFS 2018/2019.

For example, I have 3 builds:

1. Build Tests (compile etc)
2. Run parallel tests
3. Run non parallel tests

The last 2 builds are triggered from the first build.
Each of them has their tests summarize.
I want to see a summarize of both builds (how many tests in total from all builds past, failed, did not run) in the main build.

Comment: So,you would like to get the logs of selected builds? am i right ?

Comment: Tests results of the triggered builds.

Comment: ok,so you want to get logs from build,could you please provide the image of test result ?